# Add an Image column to a WPF datagrid and populate according to the first two characters in another column

Tags: wpf, image, datagrid

I am a bit new to how wpf datagrids work, and I have a project which, given an airport IATA code will display the current arrival and departure flights for that airport in a wpf datagrid.

The flight data is taken from the website [www.avionio.com](http://www.avionio.com), and as this website is multi-lingual, the column headers will change dependent on the language selected. For example, below is the English version of the arrival flights into London Heathrow:

[image]

and this is the German version:

[image]

Because the column headers are dynamic based on the language selected, they are populated by the 'DataTable.Columns.Add' method and the rows being added to the datatable via the DataRow method, before finally setting the datagrid source to the datable.

This all works fine and the datagrid is updated correctly depending on which language is selected.

What I now want to do is instead of the 'Airline' column displaying the airline name as text, I would like it to show the airline logo, which can be taken from the following site https://pics.avs.io/71/25. This site uses the first two characters of the flight number to reference the correct airline logo, so for the first flight in the datagrid above (Lufthansa) the full URL would be https://pics.avs.io/71/25/LH.png.

My question is how do I replace the Airline column on the datagrid with the relevant airline logo depending on the first two characters in the corresponding 'Flight' column.

The language I am using is C# and below is the existing code I have that populates the datagrid:

Using the webpage https://www.avionio.com/widget/en/LHR/arrivals (this displays the current London Heathrow arrivals in English. I firstly get the HTML code behind the website via this code:

```
public static string MakeRequest(string URL)
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Stream response = resp.GetResponseStream();
                        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(response, Encoding.UTF8);
                        return readStream.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        resp.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && ex.Response != null)
                {
                    var resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                    if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Details unavailable or URL airport name incorrect", "Cannot Retrieve Details", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                        return "N/A";
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
```

I then pick out the column headings from this code (as they vary by language chosen) via:

```
int startPos = 0;
int endPos = 0;

List<string> colHeaderText = new List<string>();
startPos = arrivalsDoc.IndexOf("<table class=\"timetable\">");
string colHeaders = arrivalsDoc.Substring(startPos, arrivalsDoc.Length - startPos);
startPos = colHeaders.IndexOf("<th>");
colHeaders = colHeaders.Substring(startPos, colHeaders.Length - startPos);
endPos = colHeaders.IndexOf("</tr>");
colHeaders = colHeaders.Substring(0, endPos);
string delimiter = "</th>";
string[] colHeadersSplit = colHeaders.Split(new[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
colHeaderText.Clear();
foreach (var item in colHeadersSplit)
{
    if (item != "")
    {
         string headerText = item.Replace("<th>", "").Replace("</th>", "").Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","").Trim();
         if (headerText != "")
         {
             colHeaderText.Add(headerText);
         }
     }
 }
```

And add to a DataTable via:

```
DataTable dtArrivals = new DataTable();
dtArrivals.Columns.Add(colHeaderText[0], typeof(string));                                  //Scheduled
dtArrivals.Columns.Add(colHeaderText[4].ToString(), typeof(string));            //Airline
dtArrivals.Columns.Add(colHeaderText[5].ToString(), typeof(string));            //Flight No
dtArrivals.Columns.Add(colHeaderText[3].ToString(), typeof(string));            //Origin
dtArrivals.Columns.Add(colHeaderText[2].ToString(), typeof(string));            //Status
```

I then extract each row of data from the HTML code into separate variables in a similar way to the above and populate a new row of the datatable via

```
DataRow drArrivalFlight = dtArrivals.NewRow();
drArrivalFlight[0] = scheduled + " " + flightDate;
drArrivalFlight[1] = airline;
drArrivalFlight[2] = flightNo;
drArrivalFlight[3] = origin;
drArrivalFlight[4] = status;
dtArrivals.Rows.Add(drArrivalFlight);
```

I finally populate the datagrid via:

```
dgCurrentArrivals.ItemsSource = dtArrivals.DefaultView;
```

I haven't tried anything yet as I am not familiar with wpf datagrids, and have only just successfully populated the datagrid with text values, so wouldn't know where to start with an image column.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: are you using MVVM or code behind?  could you show your xaml (view) code?

Comment: @Frenchy MVVM and code-behind are not mutual exclusive. One is a design pattern and the latter is a compiler feature. By definition, a design pattern must always be compiler/language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify autogenerated columns by handling the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumns` event. Listening to this event allows you to reorder or to filter/replace columns.

The following example allows to have a dynamic `DataGrid` by only defining the logo column explicitly.
The `Image` control which is used to display the logos will automatically download the images from an URL which is provided by the cell value.

It's important to note that the `WebRequest` class and all its associated classes are deprecated. Microsoft states that we should no longer use them. Instead, we must use the `HttpClient` class (`WebClient` is also deprecated).

1. Fix the HTTP request related code. Using the recommended `HttpClient` allows to use async APIs, which will improve the performance:

```cs
private async Task RunCodeAsync()
{
  string arrivalsDoc = await MakeRequestAsync("https://www.avionio.com/widget/en/LHR/arrivals");

  // TODO::Parse result and create DataTable
}

public async Task<string> MakeRequestAsync(string url)
{
  using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
  try
  {
    // Will throw if the status code is not in the range 200-299.
    // In case the exception is handled locally, 
    // to further improve performance you should avoid the exception
    // and instead replace the following line with a conditional check 
    // of the 'HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode' property.
    _ = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  }
  catch (HttpRequestException)
  {
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
      _ = MessageBox.Show("Details unavailable or URL airport name incorrect", "Cannot Retrieve Details", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
      return "N/A";
    }

    return "";
  }

  string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  return responseBody;
}
```

2. You should add an extra column `AirlineLogo` to your `DataTable` that contains the path to the icon:

```cs
DataTable dtArrivals = new DataTable();
dtArrivals.Columns.Add(colHeaderText[0], typeof(string));     
dtArrivals.Columns.Add(colHeaderText[4], typeof(string));     
dtArrivals.Columns.Add(colHeaderText[5], typeof(string));     
dtArrivals.Columns.Add(colHeaderText[3], typeof(string));     
dtArrivals.Columns.Add(colHeaderText[2], typeof(string));     

// Append the logo column. 
// The column name will be replaced with the "Airline" column name later.
dtArrivals.Columns.Add("AirlineLogo", typeof(string));
```

3. Then map each row to the corresponding airline logo resource. This path can be a the original URL that points to a web resource, for example `"https://pics.avs.io/71/25/LH.png"`:

```cs
DataRow drArrivalFlight = dtArrivals.NewRow();
drArrivalFlight[0] = scheduled + " " + flightDate;
drArrivalFlight[1] = airline;
drArrivalFlight[2] = flightNo;
drArrivalFlight[3] = origin;
drArrivalFlight[4] = status;

// Compose the URL to the logo using the first two letters of the flight ID
drArrivalFlight["AirlineLogo"] = $"https://pics.avs.io/71/25/{flightNo[0..2]}.png";

dtArrivals.Rows.Add(drArrivalFlight);
```

4. Define the template for the replaced column so that it will fetch the image from the URL to display it (by using the `Image` control):

```xml
<Window>
  <DataGrid x:Name="dgCurrentArrivals" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="AirlineLogoColumn">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>

              <!-- Bind the Image to the URL value of the 'AirlineLogo' column of the DataTable -->
              <Image Source="{Binding [AirlineLogo]}"
                     Height="24" />

              <!-- Bind to airline name column -->
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding [1]}" />
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

5. Hide/replace the `Airline` column using the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event:

```cs
private const int ReplacedColumnIndex = 1;
private string ReplacedColumnName { get; set; }
private int CurrentColumnIndex { get; set; }

private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  if (this.CurrentColumnIndex == ReplacedColumnIndex)
  {
    // Store the column name of the actual language
    this.ReplacedColumnName = e.PropertyName;

    // Hide the column
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
  else if (e.PropertyName == "AirlineLogo")
  {
    var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    var dataGridImageColumn = dataGrid.Resources["AirlineLogoColumn"] as DataGridColumn;
    
    // Reorder replaced column
    dataGridImageColumn.DisplayIndex = ReplacedColumnIndex;

    // Rename replaced column with the name of the current table language
    dataGridImageColumn.Header = this.ReplacedColumnName;

    // Replace the auto generated text column with our custom image column
    e.Column = dataGridImageColumn;
  }

  this.CurrentColumnIndex++;
}
```

Comment: sorry about the delay in replying. I have finally had time to try your code and it is working brilliantly, thank you.

One thing I have noticed is that for certain flights the https://pics.avs.io site sometimes does not contain the airline logo. In these scenarios, the site seems to return a default logo. 

Is here is a way of replacing this default logo with the Airline name (which is the replaced column), but keep the other airline logos if they exist on the website - ie potentially have a mixture of images and text in the same column?

Comment: The problem is that you will always get an image with the expected name from the URL. And you can only know if the image is a logo or dummy when you actually *see* it. Unless you run some image detection algorithm on the image you won't be able to distinguish. Maybe you should always show both columns (name + logo). Or find a better resource. You can even manually search and download all airline logos from different resources and store them locally to ship them along with the application. This way you can ensure that all logos are valid.

Comment: Additionally, Servers can be down or URLs die too. Remote resources are never reliable. So just search the internet for some nice logos of every airline you wish to support. In this case you would have full control over when to show the downloaded logo or the text.

Comment: I guessed this was going to be tricky to achieve so I've gone with your suggestion of keeping the airline name column visible. I've also noted your comments about downloading logos, so I've changed the code to look in a local folder first, and then only download and save if it can't find the logo in the folder. That way the logos should gradually build up in the local folder and negate the need for any downloads. Many thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Sounds good. You can also modify the image column template. When you stack the image on top of a TextBlock that holds the airline name you gracefully merged both columns. When there is a logo the cell shows both, name below logo. If there is no logo the cell only shows the name. I'm happy you found my efforts helpful.

Comment: Can you advise how I would go about 'stacking the image on top of a TextBlock that holds the airline name'?

Comment: I have updated the answer, the XAML part. The column template now contains a StackPanel that hosts the Image and a TextBlock that binds to the airline name column.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks a lot. I didn't realise you could bind to a column position - I thought it had to be the column header text.

Comment: Yes, both work. You are binding to a DataTable. DataTable has two indexers: a int indexer to access data by column index and a string indexer to access data by column name.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a solution which simplify some parts of your program and show how to bind image to datagrid. Its no easy to do that by programmation, the use of xaml simplify the task. So i suggest you to review your program, because its really impossible to use it, because really complex...

1. add the nuget package HtmlAgility Pack (simplify the search of tag in html file)
2. declare your DataGrid in the Xaml view.

**MainWindow.xaml (Main view)**

```
<Window x:Class="TestDatagrid.MainWindow" Name="Root"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDatagrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding ElementName=Root}" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding Data.Headers[0], Source={StaticResource proxy}}" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Scheduled}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding Data.Headers[4], Source={StaticResource proxy}}" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Logo}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Data.Headers[5], Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
                                    Binding="{Binding Flight}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Data.Headers[3], Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
                                    Binding="{Binding From}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Data.Headers[2], Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
                                    Binding="{Binding Status}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestDatagrid
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public List<Arrival> Arrivals = new List<Arrival>();
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        public List<string> Headers { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            var html = MakeRequest("https://www.avionio.com/widget/en/lhr/arrivals");
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            //get headers from html file 
            Headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/thead/tr/th").Select(x => x.InnerText).ToList();
            //get datas from TimeTables (get tag tr with 2 classes, one class is timetable-record)
            var TimeTables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr[contains(@class,'timetable-record')]")
                                             .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Split(' ').Count() == 2)
                                             .Select(x => 
                                             {
                                                 var dt = x.SelectNodes(".//td").Select(a =>
                                                 {
                                                     if (a.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("timetable-flight"))
                                                     {
                                                         var y = a.SelectSingleNode(".//a");
                                                         return y.InnerText;
                                                     }
                                                     return a.InnerText;
                                                 }).ToArray();

                                                 return dt;
                                             }).ToArray();

            #region Load new logo from internet and save in folder for future use
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\files").Select(x => x.Split('\\').Last()).ToList();
            var flags = TimeTables.Select(x => $"{x.Last()[0..2]}.png");
            var newFlags = flags.Except(files).ToList();        

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            //download new flags and add to files list
            var folderTosaveLogos = @"D:\files\";
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                foreach (var flag in newFlags)
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(new Uri($"https://pics.avs.io/71/25/{flag}"), $"{folderTosaveLogos}{flag}");
                    files.Add(flag);
                }
            }
            #endregion
            #region Create the global list Arrivals)
            foreach (var t in TimeTables)
            {
                var f = new Arrival();
                f.Scheduled = t[0];
                f.Date = t[1];
                f.Status = t[2];
                f.From = t[3];
                f.Airline = t[4];
                f.Flight = t[5];
                f.Logo = @$"D:\files\{f.Flight[0..2]}.png";
                Arrivals.Add(f);
            }
            #endregion
        }

        private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ... Assign ItemsSource to Arrivals List.
            var grid = sender as DataGrid;
            grid.ItemsSource = Arrivals;
        }
        public static string MakeRequest(string URL)
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Stream response = resp.GetResponseStream();
                        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(response, Encoding.UTF8);
                        return readStream.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        resp.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && ex.Response != null)
                {
                    var resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                    if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Details unavailable or URL airport name incorrect", "Cannot Retrieve Details", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                        return "N/A";
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

---

**the Class Arrival.cs**

```
namespace TestDatagrid
{
    public class Arrival
    {
        public string Scheduled { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Airline { get; set; }
        public string Flight { get; set; }
        public string Logo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

you have to create a binding Proxy for Datagrid (see [DataContext for Datagrid](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)

**BindingProxy.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestDatagrid
{
    public class BindingProxy : Freezable
    {
        #region Overrides of Freezable
        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new BindingProxy();
        }
        #endregion

        public object Data
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

---

**Result:**

[image: Resultat]

---

So study my program to use the power of xaml and binding

Comment: @ Frenchy - sorry about the delay in replying. I have finally had time to try your code and it is working brilliantly, thank you.

One thing I have noticed is that for certain flights the https://pics.avs.io site sometimes does not contain the airline logo. In these scenarios, the site seems to return a default logo. 

Is here is a way of replacing this default logo with the Airline name (which is the replaced column), but keep the other airline logos if they exist on the website - ie potentially have a mixture of images and text in the same column?

Comment: yes its possible to mix both but its another problem i suggest you to open a new question with this problem to avoid to pulltute this post...dont forget to close by upvoting.validating the answer you prefer to close the post...

Comment: @user3147092 dont forget to close the question by validating the answer you prefer...and open a new question if its necessary...